# How to add ohci_pci to initram

Tags: installation, boot, initramfs

Hello i just downloaded the ubuntu 13.10 and installed it on my computer. Rebooted and it wanted to me to unlock a disk with the passphrase i put. I noticed my keyboard wasn't working and i went to google on my laptop. Eventually i came to 1 post of my hour search that said anything to help me.

"From a live CD you should be able to open your encrypted root, then set up a chroot there and update the initramfs on the boot partition"

Now i booted up the live cd and i went into "try ubuntu" so i could try and get a console window open and figure this out. Now i have no idea how to add this i don't even know what it is a module? to whatever this file is. Im about pre-school level into this and have no idea what anything is saying.

I figured i already deleted my entire computer on win 7 so i might as well keep on going. Could anyone help me out im just trying to get my keyboard to work so i get finally just get into the desktop without using the "Try ubuntu" with the cd

Answer (score 0):

OK, let me try to decipher a bit.

You installed Ubuntu 13.10 by erasing your entire computer and installing from an Ubuntu disc.

After the installation, when the computer was booting up, you were prompted for a password.

*Question 1: Is this the first time you were prompted for a password or has this always happened when you turned the computer on*

*Question 2: Did you select the 'encrypt your home directory' option during installation?*

After you entered the pasword (which I'm assuming you used your keyboard to do) you entered Ubuntu and discovered your keyboard was not working.

*Question 3: Do you have a wireless keyboard?*

During your search (which was to attempt to fix your keyboard) you discovered a post relating to `initramfs`.

*Question 4: What made you believe this post was relevant to your keyboard?*

`initramfs` is used for several purposes, but most commonly it is for booting your OS from a RAM disk. I don't think this applies to your situation, so we're going to skip the rest of that paragraph.

So your goal is to have a clean working copy of Ubuntu. Good news, that's not terribly difficult since you're OK with wiping your computer. My first suggestion however is to switch to a simple keyboard if you have one. No wireless, USB preferably, without any fancy gaming buttons or screens. If you don't have one of these available we can try other options, but nearly all simple USB keyboards work out-of-the-box. (To be honest, nearly all keyboards work out-of-the-box, but for the sake of simplicity lets try to reduce variables).

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1238194